# Server application: Reduce cpu usage in main loop (checking if data available etc.)

Tags: java

I'm currently developing a Java server application and got a problem.
In my `Server` class I have a big while loop that continuously checks if any client has data to read or if data is available to send to any client.

This while loop uses a lot of cpu and I want to reduce it.
Until now I only could reduce it by letting the Thread sleep for 1ms at the end of each cycle but that is not the very best practice I guess.
I think what I can is to setup a `Queue` that holds all packages that shall be send and then use the wait/notify methods.
But I have no clue how to do this (or something else) for reading if any client has data to read.

Currently I do this to check if any data is available:

```
while(true){

    /* Do some stuff */

    try {
        if(client.getSocket().getInputStream().available() > 0){
            if(client.getSocket().getInputStream().read(client.getReadBuffer()) == 1){
                PacketHandler.handlePacket(client, client.getReadBuffer()[0], this);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.fine("Exception while reading data.");
        LOG.fine(e.getMessage());
        disconnectClient(client);
    }

    /* Do some stuff */
}
```

Any advice how to what I can do / look for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [Thread.yield()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29), and second the `client.getSocket().getInputStream().available()` method tells you exactly how many byte(s) you can read without blocking. Read that many, then call yield.